# Stacking boxes into a limited height box, all with same width and length, only heights change

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, queueing-theory

My problem is as follows:
I have ordered boxes to stack into a huge box. 
All the boxes including the huge box have the same width and length.
The huge box has a constant height $H$.
All the other boxes have random heights $h_i$, that are of smaller or equal height as the huge box, $h_i \leq H$.
I am trying to find the probability distribution of having n boxes that fill into the huge box.
That is:
$P(1~\text{box})= P(\ h_1 \leq H\ \& \ h_1+h_2 > H)$
$P(2~\text{boxes})= P(\ h_1+h_2 \leq H\ \&\ h_1+h_2+h_3 > H)$
and so on.
These expressions are what I am trying to develop.
Can we consider  $P(h_1 \leq H)$ and $P(h_1+h_2 > H)$ independent? In this case, it is the simple multiplication of the probabilities. Otherwise, how can I go through calculations.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please provide more context. For example, you can add some attempts you have done.

Comment: The first direct question is, is it correct to write \
$P(2 boxes only fit in the box)=P( h1+h2<=H & h1+h2+h3>H)=P( h1+h2<=H )\times P (h1+h2+h3>H)$

Comment: What is the distribution on $h_i$? Uniform?

Comment: We can consider it to be uniform, but at this stage we don't need the distribution of $h_i$

Answer (score 1):

The space of outcomes of the $n$ heights is the hypercube with sides equal to $H$. Its volume is $H^n$.

The space of heights that will fit into the box is $$0\le x_1+...+x_n\le H$$ This forms a simplex in $\mathbb R^n$ whose volumes is $\frac{H^n}{n!}$

Dividing the two gives the probability as $\frac{1}{n!}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, indeed it is interesting to think of the $n$-D problem.
However, my problem is much simpler because it is concerned with only one-D stacking. Thank you again.

Comment: @user1101361 This is a solution to your problem. You have $n$ choices for the heights of the boxes. You must consider all the possibilities for their heights. That's what the two hyper-volumes represent.

Comment: @user1101361 This solution works if you want the probability that all the $n$ small boxes you have fit into the big box. But I understood your question to be that if you have $n$ boxes, you want the probability that 1 fits (this probability is 1), or that 2 fit (this is not 1 but could be near if you have a big $n$, so the probability that 2 of them have hight less than $H/2$ is big), the probability that  3 fit, a.s.o.

Comment: @user1101361 There was a mistake in the original post. I have edited it.

Comment: @Ingix Thank you for your support but there was a mistake in my answer. The total space of outcomes is not a simplex but a hypercube. I have fixed the error. The current answer is correct.